# Laravel Table Class Autocomplete in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete, laravel

I'm using laravel for my current project. Currently I have using [Auto-complete](http://forums.laravel.com/viewtopic.php?id=742#p5330) method. Everything works perfectly, But in the migration file, auto complete is not working. For Example:

```
Schema::create('users', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

When i typed `$table->` I need to auto pop up all methods that's available in `Table` Class.

Answer (score 0):

Either add type of variable in `@var` comment before using `$table`:

```
/* @var $table \Laravel\Database\Schema\Table */
$table->increments('id');
```

Or typehint it in function declaration:

```
Schema::create('users', function(\Laravel\Database\Schema\Table $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had posted about netbeans code complition for the topic you linked.
I think it is NetBeans5.2's bug.
Yesterday, I spend a few hours to solve this. But I couldn't find solution.
NetBeans handled $table as argument. It is good. But ignored @var declear.
Also no effective @param for a closure.
So the best way is report this to NetBeans bug tracker.
I'm not native English speaker, so I can't explain well.